# How to file a bug for the AOSP?

Tags: android, bug-tracking

this isn't directly a question about android development, but about how to file a bug report if you found a bug within the android OS.

I have seen this documentation link: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/report-bugs

which finally leads to this bug-tracking system:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:190923

I created a bug report there, however, after creating it I get an error message saying:

```
New issue created: 259508180 (view access not granted)
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Perhaps it was a temporary problem? I just created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296559906 using https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Comment: Yes you are right, I was also able to create it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been temporary. In future, https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-check-downtime-history-of-a-website contains some good ways to see whether a website is experiencing a temporary issue:

- https://qr.ae/py6Dle states http://currentlydown.com/ includes availability history

whereas

- https://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html
- https://silentdown.com/
- https://sitereport.netcraft.com/

should provide this too, but also provide notification of when it's unavailable.

Comment: Wanted to be able to set this as resolved. I'm sure you knew this anyway.